# Newtonsoft.JSON - Why an error during deserializing stringified JSON schema

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema, json-deserialization

I'm receiving data from a client that represents a function in a ChatGPT API request, viewable here: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create.

I would expect the received JSON to be parsed by *Newtonsoft.Json* and then for the JSchema parsing to happen during the JSON parsing, but it seems that perhaps JSchema parsing is happening before the normal JSON parsing, and that my `[JsonIgnore]` attribute is, ironically, being ignored by the JSchema parsing.

**Here are my primary questions:**

- Why does handling `json1` in the below for loop cause an error?
- Why does the JSchema parser expect an object or a boolean when the type of `ParametersJson` is a string?
- Is there not a practical way to encode the JSON like I have it in `json1` and have it all deserialized how I expect it to be, without error? I'd like to keep the JSON schema represented as a string on the client side.

Here is the error:

> Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchemaReaderException: Unexpected token encountered when reading schema. Expected StartObject, Boolean, got String. Path 'parameters', line 7, position 9.
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Infrastructure.JSchemaReader.EnsureToken(JsonReader reader, String name, List`1 tokenTypes, String errorMessage)

Here is the .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GE8OMP

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json0 = @"
{
    'Name': 'TestFunction',
    'Description': 'This is a test function.',
    'parameters': 
    {
        'type': 'object', 
        'properties': 
        {
            'prop1': 
            {
                'type': 'string'
            }
        }
    }
}".Replace("'", "\"");
        string json1 = @"
{
    'Name': 'TestFunction',
    'Description': 'This is a test function.',
    'parameters': 
    '{
        'type': 'object', 
        'properties': 
        {
            'prop1': 
            {
                'type': 'string'
            }
        }
    }'
}".Replace("'", "\"");
        var arr = new[]{json0, json1};
        foreach (var json in arr)
        {
            Function deserializedFunction = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Function>(json);
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {deserializedFunction.Name}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Description: {deserializedFunction.Description}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Parameters: {deserializedFunction.Parameters}");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        }
    }
}

#nullable enable
public class Function
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the function to be called. Must be a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or contain underscores and dashes, with a maximum length of 64.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A description of what the function does, used by the model to choose when and how to call the function.
    /// </summary>
    public string? Description { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The parameters the functions accepts, described as a JSON Schema object.
    /// <br></br>
    /// <br></br>
    /// To describe a function that accepts no parameters, provide the value {"type": "object", "properties": { } }.
    /// </summary>
     // Need to convert from string coming from client to the JSchema object.
    [JsonIgnore]
    public JSchema Parameters { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("parameters")]
    public string ParametersJson { get => Parameters.ToString(); set => Parameters = JSchema.Parse(value); }

    public Function(string name, string? description, JSchema parameters)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your second JSON, the `parameters` value is a string. Sound like you want to deserialize the JSON string for `parameters` into `JsonSchema`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is your second JSON is invalid:

1. The quotes in the value for the `parameters` are needed to be escaped (`\"`).
2. The string value cannot be with multiple lines in the JSON.

The correct JSON should be:

```
{
    "Name": "TestFunction",
    "Description": "This is a test function.",
    "parameters": "{\"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": {\"prop1\": {\"type\": \"string\"}}}"
}
```

Assume that you have fixed the JSON issues, for the constructor you should handle the `parameters` with multiple types:

1. Change the `parameters` type to `JToken` in the constructor to allow the value in multiple types.
2. Handle the `parameters.Type` for different `JTokenType` (`String`, `Object`).

```cs
public Function(string name, string? description, JToken parameters)
{
    Name = name;
    Description = description;
        
    if (parameters.Type == JTokenType.String)
    {
        Parameters = JSchema.Parse(parameters.ToString());
    }
    else if (parameters.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        Parameters = parameters.ToObject<JSchema>();
    }
}
```

Note the `if-else` statement for handling different `JTokenType` can also simplified to:

```cs
Parameters = JSchema.Parse(parameters.ToString());
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sFPmql)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you need to fix json1

```
    string json1 = @"
{
    'Name': 'TestFunction',
    'Description': 'This is a test function.',
    'parameters': 
    '{
        'type': 'object', 
        'properties': 
        {
            'prop1': 
            {
                'type': 'string'
            }
        }
    }'
}".Replace("'{", "{").Replace("}'", "}").Replace("'", "\"");
```